# How to reuse AWS Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an angular application ERP than is designed to run on different local environments for different clients, each hosted using AWS S3. Each of these applications will have their own dedicated API Gateways, using Lambda functions pointing to their respective PostgreSQL databases in Amazon Aurora RDS. The Lambda functions that I currently use points to a single db, an example of which is as follows:

```
var pg = require("pg");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var conn = "//Connection string to a single PostgreSQL DB in Amazon Aurora RDS (postgres://username:password@url.region.amazonaws.com:port/dbname)";
    var client = new pg.Client(conn);
    client.connect();

    //var id = event.id;
    
    console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database');

    var query = client.query(`//SQL Query`);
    console.log(query);
    
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        console.log(jsonString);
        client.end();
        context.succeed(jsonObj);
    });
};
```

How do I turn Lambda functions like these into a service (Functions-as-a-service, FaaS), so I can reuse the same functions in different API Gateways that point to their respective databases (all that have the same structure and tables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have different API Gateways for your different clients, you can use [*Stage Variables*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html).

For example, lets imagine you have two clients called *Awesome Ales* and *Great Gins*. For both you have two stages each, called *Staging* and *Production*. You want to use a different RDS database for each client and each stage.

| Client | Staging | Production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Awesome Ales | awesome_ales_staging | awesome_ales_production |
| Great Gins | great_gins_staging | great_gins_production |

Now you need to set the names of those names as stage variable for their respective clients and stages and then in your Lambda, you read the name of the stage variable from the Lambdas `event`.

If you use proxy integration for the Lambda and your stage variable is called `dbname`, it will be accessible as `event.stageVariables.dbname`:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    const dbname = event.stageVariables.dbname
    var conn = "postgres://username:password@url.region.amazonaws.com:port/" + dbname;
    var client = new pg.Client(conn);
}
```

Comment: When I try to add in stage variable to my lambda function in the API Gateway, I get an error message saying "Unable to build URI with received parameters". What could this mean?

Comment: @NoohAhamad please create a new question for this issue. It is really hard with those few details to judge what is happening etc.